# pushState() not working on beforeunload, popState() not working on load, History API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history

I have a website. The main page consists of various content sections that fade in and out when clicking certain buttons. I very simply would like to push the state of two important objects that contain the relevant state info when a user clicks off of the page. This way, when they return, the correct content is showing and the correct button is highlighted. I do this before the page unloads like so:

```
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
        history.pushState(nodeContainer, '', currNode.contentId);
        history.pushState(currNode, '', currNode.contentId);
      return;
    });
```

When the page reloads I call the popstate method like so:

```
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
        console.log('Event ', e);
    });
```

This however, does not work. The popstate method is only called when clicking back twice which returns a null state object. I'm aware of similar questions on SO and have done my research. Has not helped.

Answer (score 0):

beforeUnload will only process synchronous request. You'll need to find a way to block the event loop. I've used this in the past to send a synchronous request to the server, to check if a user was downloading a file, and warn them that leaving would stop the download.

there also is the off chance that a browser could ignore the code if it believes that it can cause a popup.

more info here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: So I was able to move the pushState function to another logical location, but am still experiencing a page refresh on back and require another page back press to get a popstate (which has successfully stored the object).

Comment: I'm sure what your doing at this point. are you closing the page, then reopening it, then trying to use the same html state? the push state is powerful for single page applications, where you load index.html once.

Comment: You know what, I don't think I'm using the history api appropriately. What I need to do is preserve the state of an object before I navigate to a subpage (different html file) so that when I navigate back to it (by clicking back), it can be reset.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`History.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState). That would allow you to add extra data to the current history entry. Each call to [`History.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) will create a new page navigation inside your history stack. That's why you need to do multiple navigations before arriving at the right page.

Also, the `popstate` event will only be called when you navigate while your page is already loaded. So you'll want to read from [`History.state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/state) during your page load. That way you can check if there's state data that you can use when you initialise your page.